# How can I pass a string through volley jsonObjectRequest post mehod?

Tags: android, post, android-volley

this gives me error as it expects only JSON object as parameter.is there a way to pass string in POST request? i need to pass an encrypted string.

```
 public JsonObjectRequest addContact(String url, final String contactString, final AddContactCallback addContactCallback) {

     final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, contactString, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            if (response.length() > 0 && response.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                                if (response.getString("message").equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {// registration

                                    addContactCallback.onAddContactRequestSuccess(....);

                                } 
                            }else {
                                addContactCallback.onAddContactRequestError(new VolleyError());
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            addContactCallback.onAddContactRequestError(new VolleyError());
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        if (error instanceof NetworkError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                            addContactCallback.onNetworkError();
                        } else {
                            addContactCallback.onAddContactRequestError(error);
                        }
                    }
                });
                jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                        10000,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
                return jsonObjectRequest;
            }
```

Comment: have you tried this new JsonObject(contactJSON) in place of contactJSON ?

Comment: ya.it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.override getBody method and pass the string as byteArray.in the JsonObjectRequest constructor pass null in place of jsonobject

```
{
            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() {

                byte[] body = new byte[0];
                try {
                    body = contactString.getBytes("UTF-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

                }
                return body;
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

i am assuming u want pass a parameter in body of post request there is method for this in volley

```
  @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("stringKey", YOUR_ACTUAL_STRING);

            return params;
        }
```

for your case

```
final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, contactString, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        if (response.length() > 0 && response.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                            if (response.getString("message").equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {// registration

                                addContactCallback.onAddContactRequestSuccess(....);

                            } 
                        }else {
                            addContactCallback.onAddContactRequestError(new VolleyError());
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        addContactCallback.onAddContactRequestError(new VolleyError());
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if (error instanceof NetworkError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                        addContactCallback.onNetworkError();
                    } else {
                        addContactCallback.onAddContactRequestError(error);
                    }
                }
            }){
              @Override
              protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
              Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
              params.put("stringKey", YOUR_ACTUAL_STRING);
               return params;
    };
            jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                    10000,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            return jsonObjectRequest;
        }
```

Comment: if i need to pass just a string ,not like a key-value pair is there a way?

Comment: @ben10 AFAIK `NO`

Comment: can you send me api url      and that string and how are testing if its working or not

Comment: because server side needs key to get value

Comment: @Avinash is key a must to get value in case of post request?

Comment: yes otherwise if there are many parameters that u want send but server couldn't differentiate between them and couldn't know which parameter is for what.So its needed

Comment: @Avinash actually this string is an encrypted Jsonobject

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149805/discussion-between-avinash-and-ben10).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send the string to server through jsonObjectRequest post methord so you need make the key and value pair to send over the server

like as:

```
JSonObject jsonobjest=new JSonObject();
jsonObject.put(Key_name,String_value);
```

and send this jsonobject over the server using the jsonObjectRequest same as over here.
its work me,you can use it.